Motor details - lead lugs and other items
I'm trying to evaluate a replacement motor using limited data from the existing motor.
The vendor provided a motor datasheet, which includes some "special features", but the lines run together, and it's hard to tell which things go together.
Specifically, it says (formatting as original):
PAINT PER ANSIZ55.1 NO. 61 LIGHT GRAY COMPRESSION TYPE
LEAD LUGS 3/8IN X 16 TAPPED HOLE IN MTR FRAME
FOR GROUNDING CORROSION RESISTANT SCREENS
XT FEATURES STAINLESS STEEL N/P WATERTIGHT
C/B ONE SIZE OVERSIZE C/B
What I think this means is that it has compression type lugs, it has a 3/8IN-16 tapped hole in the motor frame to connect a ground to, it has corrosion resistant screens (Its a WP1 motor), and it has a stainless steel conduit box (oversized by one standard size) but it is not provided as watertight.
Does this seem right?

sounds right ...
